# Submit AJAX and Springboot values

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I want to send the URI value to the database using AJAX and the request is written in @Controller. But when I hit submit there's nothing in the database.
For example I have the address:

```
http://localhost:8080/post/view/2
```

As above I want to save value 2 to my database every time I click submit. I have tried but nothing

@Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="post/view/{id}", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces = "apllication/json")
    public @ResponseBody Comment newComment (@RequestParam(name="id") Long id)  {
     Comment comment = new Comment();
     
        
        Post postView = postService.findById(id);
         
        
        comment.setPoster(postView);
        commentService.create(comment);
        return comment;     
    }
```

And my code HTML

view.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head >
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" 
    src="https://www.technicalkeeda.com/js/javascripts/plugin/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://www.technicalkeeda.com/js/javascripts/plugin/json2.js"> 
   </script>
    <title th:text="${postView.title}">View Post</title>
   <script >
  function madeAjaxCall(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:3313/post/view/{id}"
    
   
       }
        </script>
      </head>

   <body>
   <div>
    <form  method="post" >
   <main id="posts">
  <article>
    <h2 class="title" th:text="${postView.title}">Post Title</h2>
    <div class="date">
        <i>Posted on</i>
       
        <span th:if="${postView.author}" th:remove="tag">
            <i>by</i>
            <span th:text="${ postView.author.lastName}">Svetlin Nakov</span>
        </span>
    </div>
   
  </article>
  

 
  
   <input type="button" value="Ajax Submit" onclick="madeAjaxCall();"/>
   </main>
   </form>

   </div>
    </body>

   </html>
```

I think I was wrong or missing something at AJAX or @Controller. Thank you

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and run through the controller step by step?

Answer (score 0):

try using `@PathVariable` instead of `@RequestParam`

Comment: strange... did you try using `curl` command and POST `http://localhost:8080/post/view/2` ? I wonder if it's Controller problem or HTML problem because I wasn't sure how your html(javascript) code sets value for `{id}`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed several things that are wrong in your code:

1. `https://www.technicalkeeda.com/js/javascripts/plugin/jquery.js` this link is invalid.  Try using jQuery from the official site: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js`
2. This might not be your server url `url: "http://localhost:3313/post/view/{id}"`. Please confirm the port is 3313 and provide a valid value for `{id}`. Also, you don't need to use the port and url at all. See my code below:
3. `produces = "apllication/json"` you have typo here. Just change it to `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`
4. You are using @RequestParam but your request has the `id` parameter in path. Lookup the difference between the @RequestParam and @PathParam.
   `(@RequestParam(name="id") Long id)  {` You should be using `@PathVariable`

Here's a working code:

Backend controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/post/view/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    void newComment(@PathVariable Long id) {
        System.out.println("Requested with id = " + id);
    }
```

Frontend:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
    function madeAjaxCall() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/post/view/5"
        })
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Ajax Submit" onclick="madeAjaxCall();"/>

</body>
</html>
```